# Sqoop-export the partitioned Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a Hive table partitioned by `year` and `week` columns. So the contents are stored in multiple recursive directories in Hive warehouse and in my case I have more than 100+ directories(partitions) for this table.

Here I am not sure how to mention the hive table's directory detail to the `--export-dir` property of the `sqoop-export` command.

Do I have to individually mention all 100* directory in separate `sqoop-export` commands?. Is there any way to mention about all the nested directories in a single `sqoop-export` command?.

Kindly also let me know if there is any other better way to solve this?.

*[Note: I dont have Hcatalog in my environment, I just want to prefer the 'export to hdfs directory' as my last option ]*

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an External table with all the partitions and use the directory of external table in sqoop export.

1)  PART_TABLE (partitioned table);

2) Create exter table XX_DUMMY 
()
Location

3) Insert overwrite XX_DUMMY  as select * from PART_TABLE

4) Run the Sqoop export

Or

Try export-dir /user/name/*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the following?

> --hive-partition-key  Name of a hive field to partition are sharded on
>
> --hive-partition-value     String-value that serves as partition key for this imported into hive in this job.